# How to reload a ui view's content Swift

Tags: swift, view, reload

I have a view controller which has scroll view in it, and the scroll view has a view. So, view has a lot of buttons and labels which are being showed depending on data which comes from api. And I have a button after pressing it, I want to reload a views (it's content).

Answer (score 8):

one of the easy hack and **NOT** the recommended way is to do

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
```

also you can do `self.viewDidLoad()` OR `self.viewWillAppear(true)`

well the different recommended approaches you can use are the following

Delegation
KVO
Notifications

The other way would be to use a tableView and user `reloadData()`

Delegation: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide

KVO: https://cocoacasts.com/key-value-observing-kvo-and-swift-3/

Notifications: http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/notifications-and-userinfo-with-swift-3-0/

Comment: Adding `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` to either `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()` did not make my screen refresh. I'm coming back to a UIView from a modal if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7):

The best and proper way is to define a method that will layout each buttons, telling if it should be hidden or display and update its frame.

The easiest but ugly way is to use :

```
self.viewToReload.setNeedsLayout()
self.viewToReload.layoutIfNeeded()
```